# How i can make a "go to" button from the content of a <p> tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `<p>` tag in my HTML that receives its value from a function in javascript. The value it receives is a link (www.google.com). Use the "copytoclipboard" library to copy that link to the clipboard, but I need another button that allows me to go to that link in a different tab. What I can do?

P.S: The link always change, depending on the data of a form. (youtube, instagram, google, etc)

Comment: `window.open` ?

Comment: yeah, but the < p > tag is dynamic, the tag can receive several links depending the data of a form. How do I tell the "window.open" where it should go?

Comment: By passing it a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Use the anchor tag with attributes **rel="noopener noreferrer"**. Put your value in the href attribute.

```
<a class="linkButton" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="www.google.com"></a>
```

Style it in CSS to make it a button or however you like.